# python building egg but nothing happens

Tags: python, easy-install, egg

I'm trying to build an egg with my app, but it doesn't work.

I have easy_installed on my machine.

In the folder with app I created file setup.py with this content:

```
from setuptools import setup
```

Then I run:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_egg
```

but nothing happens. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Is anything being printed to the console? Is so, what?

Comment: The problem is nothing is printed. No Error message. There also is no no .egg file...

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and installed easy_install using apt-get install python-setuptools

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.

What helped was adding:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the beginning of the file and:

```
setup(
    name='project_name',
    version='0.1',
    description='desc',
    author='Name Surname',
    author_email='my@email.com',
    url='http://my.website.com',
    )
```

in the content below import line